# translation missing:en.admin.communities.settings.payments_not_enabled Sharetribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sharetribe

I am developing an app using sharetribe but I am unable to complete my payments setup through share tribe it always gives me this error[image]

Comment: Your question has too few information to help us to help you. What gem did you install? Where come from this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation error is indeed one thing (and recommendations from ttbohemian are great!).

However to fix the root issue that you can't finalize your payment, you should probably review your Online payment setup in the "Payment system" tab of your Sharetribe Go admin panel. There, if you have setup Stripe according to the instructions at https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe#payments, you should be able to add your Stripe account keys. Online payments should then work smoothly!

Or maybe you have added your own payment gateway to your local installation?

Comment: I have not hosted the platform yet so not able to do payments on pay pal.
Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Sounds great! If you are in a supported country, Stripe can be used as the payment gateway, out of the box ;-) Worth a try if that works in your region!

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's missing in the file en.yml the translation for `en.admin.communities.settings.payment_not_enabled`.

Not sure if you are local developing.

If you are developing in local a Rails app you need to check your yml file in `config/locales` with a structure like :

```
# config/locales/en.yml

en:
  admin:
    communities:
      settings:
        payment_not_enabled: 'Your translation is here'
```

Also, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html might help you understand the mechanics behind *internationalization*

Comment: Yes I'm using local developing enviorment

Comment: In that case, check your `en.yml` file and have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html on how internationalization works.